# c# mysql with pagination (limit) with sorting. after add new record. record will not be locate at last page

Tags: c#, mysql, limit

i'm using c#.

retrieve a batch of record example

select * from tableName order by fieldA, FieldB , FieldC limit 0, 10

after I added new record.  by right it should be able to be found in last page of my result.
but due to the sorting.  it might not be at the last page.

my question is.  how am I going to know, this record ( i have my lastCreateID) it actually located at which paging? so that i can reallocate my pagination limit to the particular page?

Regards,
MH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you'll probably have to do to know which page it's on is do something like

```
select *,@row:=@row+1 as row 
from tableName,(select @row:=0)R order by fieldA, FieldB , FieldC
```

the above is only to show that we can give it a row number using the same ordering as your pagination limit query (order by fieldA,FieldB,FieldC).
then what you'll have to do is a select like

```
select row from
(select *,@row:=@row+1 as row 
from tableName,(select @row:=0)R order by fieldA, FieldB , FieldC)T1
where yourIDcolumnName = lastCreatedId
```

to grab the row number of the last created row number, and now that you know which row it sits on, you can figure out which page it's on.

Comment: how if i have to add into mysqlcommand.parameter.  @row will be crash?

Comment: what? I don't understand your question

Comment: hi tin, thanks.  i mean user define parameter. i have solved it by adding a new word in the connection string ";Allow User Variables=True;"